# How to redirect to Details View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

This is my LearnController and here is the create.

---

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Learn learn)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Learns.Add(learn);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = learn.ModuleId });
        }

        ViewBag.ModuleId = new SelectList(db.Modules, "ModuleId", "Code", learn.ModuleId);
        return View(learn);
    }
```

---

### Here is the detail in my LearnController

```
 public ViewResult Details(int id)
    {
        var mod = db.Modules.Include("Learns").Single(g => g.ModuleId == id);
        return View(mod);
    }
```

---

In my create view of the learning controller, I place a HTMLActionLink but I can't seem to be redirected. Is there something wrong with my codes?

---

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Details")
```

---

This is the error.

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult Details(Int32)' in 'Module1.Controllers.LearnController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters

Comment: could you check the ModuleId is defined as Nullable in DB?

If yes, you need to change that.

Comment: The main reason behind it is you have passed `id` as a parameter in your details method andd you're passing module id there so its not matching with the parameters name.You should pass `id` not moduleId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link would need to be `@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Details", new { id = # })` where # is the id of the `Module` to display. So when you create a new `Learn` the GET method would need to be something like

```
public ActionResult Create(int ID) // ID is the ModuleId your creating the Learn for
{
  Learn model = new Learn();
  model.ModuleID = ID;
  return View(model);
}
```

and in the view

```
@model Learn
....
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Details", new { id = Model.ModuleID })
```

This is assuming that the `Details` view contains a link to create a new `Learn` for the `Module`, where the link would be `@Html.ActionLink("Add new Learn", "Create", new { id = Model.ID})`

If you can create a new `Learn` from some other view (where you don't have access to the `ID` property of `Module`), and where the view to create a new `Learn` allows you to select the `Module` form a drop down list, then you would need javascript/jquery to update the `href` value of the link based on the selected `Module`

Comment: A few side notes (I dont know you models so I'm making some assumptions): The `Details` method in your question is displaying the details of `Module` (including its collection of `Learn` objects) so that method should really be in a `ModuleController`. In a `Details` (or `Edit`) GET method where you pass an ID, you should get the object from the database (as you have done) then first test if its null (a user may have entered an invalid ID in the address bar), and if so, `return new HttpNotFoundResult();`

Comment: Mr Stephen could you explain to me how the code works? @Stephen

Comment: @FaizEverywhere, Which bit of code do you not understand?

Comment: The one placed in the GET method

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean.

Comment: Could you explain how these codes actually work? `public ActionResult Create(int ID) // ID is the ModuleId your creating the Learn for
{
  Learn model = new Learn();
  model.ModuleID = ID;
  return View(model);
}`

Comment: Its for generating a view to create a new `Learn`. Since `Learn` belongs to a `Module` the methods `ID` parameter is the `ModuleID` property of the `Module` to want to create the `Learn` for. It then initializes a new instance of `Learn`, sets its `ModuleID` property (so now its related to the `Module`) and then passes the instance to the view for editing.

Comment: Thank you Mr Stephen. I have two more question I would like to enquire. The first would be, 

1) Is it possible to convert the project outcome into a PDF format?

2) Please refer to this link of my colleague question.

**[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27117781/how-do-i-redirect-from-my-login-to-an-index-using-a-specific-id)**

It is much appreciated if you could assist us. @Stephen Muecke

Comment: Q1. Tha'ts and entirely different issue and you need to ask a new question. Q2. You did not include a link!

Comment: What should I include in the question for the PDF?

Comment: @FaizEverywhere. You ask me to help a colleague and I give [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27117781/how-do-i-redirect-from-my-login-to-an-index-using-a-specific-id/27119091#27117781), but you colleague has not even viewed it?

Comment: Thank you for the help @Stephen I'll tell her

Answer (score 0):

"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32", the parameters should be nullable type, change to this

```
public ViewResult Details(int? id)
{
    try
    {
      if (id.HasValue)
      {
        var mod = db.Modules.Include("Learns").Single(g => g.ModuleId == id);
        if (mod == null) 
          throw new ArgumentException("Invalid ID");
        return View(mod);
      }
      else
      {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid ID");
      }
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
      return View(new Modules());  // assumed Details view model is Modules class
    }
    catch 
    {
      return View(new Modules());  // assumed Details view model is Modules class
    }
}
```

or

```
public ViewResult Details(string id)
{
    try
    {
      int intId;
      if(int.TryParse(id, out intId))
      {
        var mod = db.Modules.Include("Learns").Single(g => g.ModuleId == intId);
        if (mod == null) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid ID");
        return View(mod);
      }
      else
      {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid ID");
      }
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
      return View(new Modules());  // assumed Details view model is Modules class
    }
    catch 
    {
      return View(new Modules());  // assumed Details view model is Modules class
    }
}
```

**Update**

I think I misunderstood your question, all you need to do is change

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Details" })
```

to

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Details", new { id = Model.ModuleId })
```

as suggested by Stephen Muecke

Comment: Thank you soo much i will try the method now

Comment: This does not allow the user to navigate back to the details view the link would always throw an exception!

Comment: The code above is for Details action not for the Create action (POST), it is just an example I instance a Modules object and pass to view (whenever exception catch in action), exception may occur in Details View depends on which properties of the Modules object would be used in View.

Comment: @bsting, But it does not address OP's question at all. And why have `int? id`? The method is for viewing the details of an existing `Module` which **will** have an `ID` so making it `nullable` and testing for `null` is pointless

Comment: @StephenMuecke the OP's question is @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Details") failed to be loaded due to the empty parameter (id=""), i would say testing on parameter at server site is not pointless, it is to handler unexpected behaviour in case client try to send an id which is not an integer value.

Comment: So instead of throwing an exception early in the pipeline, what your suggesting is that extra code should be run in order to throw a different exception. If that not pointless, what is?

Comment: Hi sorry but as Stephen Muecke said, the same error appears again? Is there a reason such an error appeared? @StephenMuecke .

Comment: @bsting Can you further explain how your code works? Or does the problem lie in my View?

Comment: @FaizEverywhere, Read my answer. This answer does not solve you problem. All it means that you get a different exception.

Comment: @FaizEverywhere, can you update your Details action code and the view of your Details, thx.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I think i misunderstood the question. Thx for your comments.